# Is there a connection between generalized ODEs and stochastic ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-analysis

I'm working on a problem where I've run into a generalized ODE

$$
\dot X \in D(X)
$$

where $D(X)$ is a continuous, compact and convex subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$. To me, this problem seems in many ways similar to problems involving stochastic differential equations (SDE).
Just out of curiosity I wonder if there are any clear parallels or direct connections between the theory of generalized odes and SDEs. If not, I would also be interested in which key way they differ.

Note that an answer in layman terms would be most helpful since I'm not a really a mathematician.

Comment: This is an interesting (albeit broad) question. Can you maybe constrain what kind of connection you're looking for?

Comment: For example, when handling SDEs, we need Ito's calculus which essentially brings in some second order differential terms. Does similar things happen when the derivative belong to a set?